# Getting error in stripe paymentsheet configuration - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, swift5

I am facing an issue while verifying the intent id in the Stripe payment sheet. Getting status failed. Using Stripe 21.9.0 - SDK

Error : PaymentSheet received a PaymentIntent in an unexpected state: STPPaymentIntentStatus

```
       
        StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey = KeyStripe
        var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
//      configuration.merchantDisplayName = ""
        
        let paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: client_secret,
            configuration: configuration)
        
        paymentSheet.present(from: self) { [weak self] (paymentResult) in
            switch paymentResult {
            case .completed:
                self?.displayAlert(title: "Payment complete!")      
            case .canceled:
                print("Payment canceled!")
            case .failed(let error):
                self?.displayAlert(title: "Payment failed", message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```